# SQL Bulk Copy into separate Tables

Tags: c#, generics, sqlbulkcopy

I want to perform insert into database but in different Tables. Each record i have in my file is assigned with the table Identifiers which will be used as a key. For now what i have done is to make it a generic approach, I have created one more file.txt in which i have specified all the identifiers with the table names. and stored it into a dictionary of string, string.

So, I have example some thing like below in my dictionary:

Table Identifier, Table Name

Table Identifier, Table Name

Then I created another dictionary of string as key (Note: I have used the previous dictionary value as a key into this dictionary) and list of string as values to get the column names of the table name.

So, No I have some thing like this below sample data into my dictionary:

Table Name, Column Names IEnumerable

Table Name, Column Names IEnumerable

Then,
The datafile.txt which contains the data as pipe delimited, I split them and saved into a List of KVP of string and List of String. As I mentioned before, I have table identifiers in my data files. So i used them as key in my KVP and store the split values into List of string.

So, No I have some thing like this below sample data into my List of KVP of string , List of string:

Table Identifier, IEnumerable Values

Table Identifier, IEnumerable Values

Now doing half of the work, I am stuck into my FINAL ISSUE:

Now I have All the identifers , Table Names, Column Names and Values with me into the dictionary and List. And only thing to do is to match and merge the records and DUMP it!

For matching: I have thought to match the List of KVP`s key with the dictionary`s key and then use the values as a key to get the Column Names.

Expected Scenario Image:

List [[List< Column Names>] , [List of String Values]]

**MY CODE:**

```
 DataTable dt = null;
    SqlConnection cn = null;
    SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
    SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    string path = string.Empty;

  public void test()
    {
        string TableIdentiferFilepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/testfile/TableIdentifer.txt");
        Dictionary<string, string> TableIdentifer_TableName = null;
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> Table_Name_ColumnName = null;

        using (reader = new StreamReader(TableIdentiferFilepath))
        {
            TableIdentifer_TableName = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Table_Name_ColumnName = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] curr = reader.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { ",", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                TableIdentifer_TableName.Add(curr[0], curr[1]);
                using (cn = new SqlConnection(ConString.Connection.conn))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        string query = string.Format("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = '{0}' order by ordinal_position", curr[1].ToString());
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn))
                            {
                                using (dt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    da.Fill(dt);
                                    List<string> dataColumns = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("column_name")).ToList();
                                    Table_Name_ColumnName.Add(curr[1], dataColumns);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/TextFile/DataSample.txt");
        List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> KVPValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>();

        using (reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] arr = reader.ReadLine().Split(new string[] { "|", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                var collValues = new List<string>();
                KVPValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(arr[0], arr.Skip(1).AsEnumerable().ToList()));

                foreach (var item in TableIdentifer_TableName)
                {
                    foreach (var item2 in Table_Name_ColumnName.Where(c => c.Key == item.Value))
                    {
                        var curr_val = item2.Value;
                        var currKey = KVPValues.Where(p => p.Key == item.Key).ToList();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a BIG PICTURE! Hopefully now people will understand what i want to achieve.

Comment: Is this that much difficult to understand or unable to help :D ??

Comment: No, it's unclear what you are asking, the question is way too verbose and it's hard to see whether it is a valid question for SO or it should be moved to Code Review.

Comment: Just to simplify this, I think i need not to explain the story here and just that what i need.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Kindly verify if its better or worse then before?

Comment: Honestly I would ask what problem are you trying to solve (big picture).  Maybe your solution is too complex because your trying to solve it in the wrong way...

Comment: The problem is need to insert the records into multiple tables thats it.

Comment: the files i have right now has its data in the text files and in it each row has the identifiers which specifies the table into which that records needs to be inserted.